# Where is Plasmashell started?

Tags: kde, desktop-environment, plasma, plasma5

`Plasmashell` does not start automatically anymore. I have to run `killall plasmashell` and `plasmashell &` every time I start my computer.

I would like to know what program or `systemd` service is responsible for starting plasmashell or in which script plasmashell is started so I can troubleshoot this problem.

```
Operating System: Manjaro Linux 
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.70.0
Qt Version: 5.14.2
Kernel Version: 5.6.15-1-MANJARO
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
Memory: 15,5 GiB of RAM
```

Answer (score 2):

First, whatever your distribution uses to select the X11 session type runs the `startkde` script, which will initialize various things and then start up `kdeinit` (possibly `kdeinit5` in some distros) and `ksmserver`.

Those two will then continue the session start-up process according to both system-wide and per-user configuration. As far as I know, `ksmserver` mostly gives the orders and `kdeinit[5]` starts the actual processes. The main exception seems to be the window manager: `kwin` or `kwin_x11`, which is started directly by `ksmserver`.

Once that is done, `ksmshell` tells `kdeinit[5]` to start `klauncher` and have it run the "autostart phase 0". This includes executing any binaries defined by `.desktop` files in both system-wide and user-specific autostart directories that have the `X-KDE-autostart-phase=0` attribute.

At least on Debian 5, the autostart of `plasmashell` is specified by `/etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.plasmashell.desktop`, which does have the `X-KDE-autostart-phase=0` set.

The session initialization and startup continues for a while after that. You can find a more verbose description of the full process [in the `ksmserver` source package README file here.](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-workspace/blob/master/ksmserver/README)

The fact that you need to run `killall plasmashell` first suggests that `plasmashell` may in fact be starting, but could be hanging for some reason: maybe because it ends up trying to start too early before the other things it needs are fully set up? In that case, you might want to investigate shifting the missing bit (whatever it is) into an earlier position in the start-up process.

Or is the `plasmashell` process you're killing left over from your *previous* session? In that case, you should investigate what happens at the end of the session also.

Comment: I always set `Start with an empty session` in `System Settings --> Desktop Session --> On Login`